# ITerm2 is not loading dotprofile so mysql command is not found

Tags: mysql, linux, macos, iterm2

i have setup and exported path inside **.bash_profile** and **.profile** as follows:

**export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin**

but everytime i open a new iterm2 terminal and run command mysql, it throws error as **"zsh: command not found: mysql"**

when i "source" it at the moment, mysql command works but again when i reload a new terminal, again it throws same error.

any idea what else i am missing in iterm2 setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin` to `.zshrc`.**
As you use `zsh`, when you open a terminal, `.zshrc` will be loaded but not `.bash_profile`.